# Proguard with OrmLite on Android

Tags: android, optimization, obfuscation, proguard, ormlite

How should I use proguard with ormlite library on Android?

Trying this:

```
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.**
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.**
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.**
```

But I get:

> 03-23 20:23:54.518: E/AndroidRuntime(3032): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cz.eman.android.cepro/cz.eman.android.cepro.activity.StationsOverviewActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find constructor that takes a Context argument for helper class class kb

I also tried to add this:

```
-keepclassmembers class * { public <init>(android.content.​Context); }
```

But I get another classmembers errors.

Comment: Did my answer help dude? If so then please accept it.  If not then please provide your own answer.

Comment: please post the answer if you have found or mark the answers as correct It can help others to find the answer

Comment: how did you fix this eventually?

Comment: I fixed it by doing all of the below (answers from Gray and German), and after that I also had to add all my database-content objects (with one or more @DatabaseField's) in my proguard config like this: -keep class com.myapp.model.**
-keepclassmembers class com.myapp.model.** { *; }

Comment: frank u saved my lifeeeee ...

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Thank you a lot for posts like this that help us to advance step by step.

I've came up with other solution after i have tried the last one without success:

```
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

I hope it can help someone.

Comment: Not enough for me.... it throws something like this:
Field class java.lang.String for field FieldType:name=b,class=Location is not valid for data persister com.j256.ormlite.field.types.DateLongType@20f95c38

Comment: To keep constructor only for your orm helper class: 

`-keepclassmembers class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper { public <init>(android.content.Context); } ` 

To keep Database classes (with DatabaseTable): `-keep @com.j256.ormlite.field.* public class *`

To keep DB fields in DB classes: `-keepclassmembers class * { @com.j256.ormlite.field. *; }`

Answer (score 20):

The accepted answer was not enough for my case, so I enhanced it and this is what I ended up with:

```
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }

# Keep the helper class and its constructor
-keep class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
}

# Keep the annotations
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Keep all model classes that are used by OrmLite
# Also keep their field names and the constructor
-keep @com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable class * {
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField <fields>;
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField <fields>;
    # Add the ormlite field annotations that your model uses here
    <init>();
}
```

Comment: After a lot of searching this was the only answer that worked for me. I had "IllegalArgumentException: Foreign field class x does not have id field" and I think the last keep block resolved it. Thank you.

Comment: And additional line fixed my error while trying to create a signed apk is: -dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.android.** with the newest 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:5.0', because com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor extends Processor.

Comment: For ORMLite 5.0 I had to add 
`-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.android.**`
`-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.logger.**`
`-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.misc.**`

Comment: This was the only one that worked for me, though in addition I had to convert all the com.j256.** to com.j256** (ie remove the dot) else I got an 'unresolved class name' red underline (Android Studio 4.1.2)

Answer (score 15):

I don't have the solution but here are a couple of references to help:

- [Proguard support request around ORMLite](http://sourceforge.net/projects/proguard/forums/forum/182456/topic/4040020/index/page/)
- [ORMLite proguard discussion #1](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ormlite-user/2X1M9mRPKvY)
- [ORMLite proguard discussion #2](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/ormlite-user/CoAsyF9AOvE)

You may be missing:

```
-keepclassmembers class * { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
}
```

and/or

```
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Comment: `-keepclassmembers class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
}`

Answer (score 3):

A small addition to the configuration above - if you're trying to serialize / deserialize Joda's `DateTime` objects via ORMLite, you probably need this as well:

```
-keepclassmembers class **DateTime {
    <init>(long);
    long getMillis();
}
```

...since ORMLite's `DateTimeType` does everything via reflection.

Comment: Thanks Thomas, funny that I found the answer I was searching for here from you :)

Comment: Hehe :) And I'm not even overly active over here.

Answer (score 1):

In addittion to default necessary for reflection:

```
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

I needed to keep all my Entity classes:

```
-keep class com.example.db.Entities.** { *; }
```

Otherwise entity classes are stripped out. 
I use predefined DB(generated earlier).

Is there an easier/better way to obfuscate. Maybe I'm keeping too many classes?

Answer (score 0):

In my case this did the trick:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable,Signature,InnerClasses,*Annotation*
```

and

```
-keepclassmembers class * {public <init>(android.content.Context);}
-keep class com.j256.** { *; }
```

With obfucation and optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

A small addition for the latest version **OrmLite 5**.

You may want to add these rows to hide some new warnings:

```
-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.android.**
-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.logger.**
-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.misc.**
```

Warnings are like these:

> Warning:com.j256.ormlite.android.OrmliteTransactionalProcessor: can't
> find referenced class javax.lang.model.SourceVersion
>
> Warning:com.j256.ormlite.logger.Slf4jLoggingLog: can't find referenced
> class org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
>
> Warning:com.j256.ormlite.misc.JavaxPersistenceImpl: can't find
> referenced class javax.persistence.Column

Answer (score -2):

I've came up with such solution (maybe will work for somebody too).

Made such changes to `proguard.cfg`:

- Added `-dontobfuscate` option
- Appended `,!code/allocation/variable` to `-optimization` option

APK file size using such configuration reduced from 580 kB to 250 kB.

Though, no obfuscation is performed.