# ADT - 20 Proguard gives error with external jars

Tags: android, proguard, ormlite, apk

Environment I am using is ADT version 20, with eclipse(Juno) version 4.2

In my android project, I need to get rid of Log before I can release it on Google Play, so I tried to use Progaurd for it, I am completely new to the progaurd, so I searched on Google and found this code snippet

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** i(...);
}
```

I have added this in the bottom of `proguard-project.txt` and in `project.properties` file I have uncomment

`proguard.config=${sdk.dir}\tools\proguard\proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt`

which is what mentioned in comment section of `project.properties` file

and after that I have exported apk, and install it in the emulator.
It shows me an error with the external jars that I have added in to my projects.

Jar that looks like creating problem is `ormlite`

am doing something wrong? something that I am missing?

please help me with this

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to exclude ORMLite classes as well.  See the following discussion about ORMLite and proguard:

> [Proguard with OrmLite on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853096/proguard-with-ormlite-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

In ADT release 20, optimization is disabled by default, so Log statements are not removed. To enable optimization, you have to select the optimizing ProGuard configuration file in `project.properties`:

```
proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android-optimize.txt:proguard-project.txt
```

Comment: I have enable the progaurd by that line of code, but It also removes some classes from ormlite.jar