# Problems with OrmLite and proguard obfuscation

Tags: android, proguard, ormlite

When I use Proguard on project with OrmLite. I recieve this **error**:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.name/com.package.name.activities.StartActivity}:
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find OpenHelperClass because none of the generic parameters of class class com.package.name.activities.StartActivity extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper.  You should use getHelper(Context, Class) instead.
```

I've tried all recomendation from [Proguard with OrmLite on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853096/proguard-with-ormlite-on-android) and from others resources but without results

Answer (score 5):

Put the below in both your proguard-project file and your proguard-optimization file (if you use optimization).

```
 # Your application may contain more items that need to be preserved; 
 # typically classes that are dynamically created using Class.forName: 
 # ormlite uses reflection 
 -keep class com.j256.** { *; }
 -keep class com.j256.**
 -keepclassmembers class com.j256.**
 -keep enum com.j256.**
 -keepclassmembers enum com.j256.**
 -keep interface com.j256.**
 -keepclassmembers interface com.j256.**

-keepclassmembers class * { 
  public <init>(android.content.Context); 
} 

-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

and for every model class:

```
-keep class com.xyz.components.**
-keepclassmembers class com.xyz.components.** { *; }
```

I don't like the last part one bit, but I'm tired of trying to find a better solution.

Answer (score 1):

I asked much the same question [crash using ORMLite on Android with proguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14264199/crash-using-ormlite-on-android-with-proguard) and the answer was to add

```
-keepattributes Signature
```

to the proguard configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following proguard configuration to Keep all model classes that are used by OrmLite

```
-keep @com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable class * {
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField <fields>;
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField <fields>;
    # Add the ormlite field annotations that your model uses here
    <init>();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a small addition for the latest version **OrmLite 5**.

You may want to add these rows to hide some new warnings:

```
-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.android.**
-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.logger.**
-dontwarn com.j256.ormlite.misc.**
```

Look for more details into this thread: "[how can i write the config of proguard for ormlite?](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/issues/44)"