# Orm Lite - Could not find public constructor that has a single (Context) argument for helper class

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using OrmLite 4.47. 
I followed many tutorials, and read others questions on stackoverflow, but I can't understand how to solve this problem.

that's the complete message

```
05-15 16:36:13.805: E/AndroidRuntime(15382): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find public constructor that has a single (Context) argument for helper class class com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
05-15 16:36:13.805: E/AndroidRuntime(15382): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context]
```

That's my databaseHelper Class

```
public class MyDatabaseHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {  

    // name of the database file for your application -- change to something  
    // appropriate for your app  
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "databas.db";  
    // any time you make changes to your database, you may have to increase the  
    // database version  
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;  

    //genera molte eccezioni
    private Dao<Truck, Integer> truckDao = null;

    //genera una sola eccezione a runtime
    private RuntimeExceptionDao<Truck, Integer> truckRuntimeDao=null;

    public MyDatabaseHelper(Context context) { 
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION); 

    } 

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            TableUtils.clearTable(connectionSource, Truck.class);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase database, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int OldVersion,
            int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            TableUtils.dropTable(connectionSource, Truck.class, true);
            onCreate(database,connectionSource);
        } catch (java.sql.SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }  

    public Dao<Truck, Integer> getTruckDao() throws java.sql.SQLException{
        if(truckDao==null){
            truckDao=getDao(Truck.class);
        }
        return truckDao;
    }

    public RuntimeExceptionDao<Truck, Integer> getTruckRuntimeExceptionDao(){
        if(truckRuntimeDao==null){
            truckRuntimeDao=getRuntimeExceptionDao(Truck.class);
        }
        return truckRuntimeDao;
    }
}
```

And I got the problem when in my activity i try to do that

```
MyDatabaseHelper helper = OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this,MyDatabaseHelper.class);
RuntimeExceptionDao<Truck, Integer> truckDao = helper.getTruckRuntimeExceptionDao();
```

So the database helper class is public, and the Activity class extends Activiy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to clean the project...it's strange because the code looks good enaugh to work :)

Answer (score 8):

For those that run into this error with minify enabled (proguard):

Add the following configuration for ormlite:

```
# ormlite
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

Check this out too [Stackoverflow - proguard-with-ormlite-on-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853096/proguard-with-ormlite-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

Check the import part of your class which uses MyDatabaseHelper class.
It seems that your getHelper method uses a wrong default constructor.

Your error message,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find public constructor that has a single (Context) argument for helper class class com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
```

If you use MyDatabaseHelper class properly , it should be

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find public constructor that has a single (Context) argument for helper class class 'yourpackage'.MyDatabaseHelper
```

For explaining error,

Default OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper class only has a constructor like below,
it doesn't have a constructor which has a single argument (context).

```
public DatabaseHelper(Context context, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, factory, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }
```

So it could cause an IllegalStateException error.

Answer (score 0):

Create an empty constructor in your POJO or bean class. Problem solve :)

EX.

```
public Truck(){

//empty constructor in custom class

}
```

Answer (score 0):

OK this how I was able to solve my problem progurad-rules didn't work for me; So what I did was, I made DatabaseHelper class constructor as public and then I initialized DatabaseHelper object passing Activity context into its constructor, in onCreate() Method of activity where I wanted to fetch data or send;

This is the public constructor,

```
 public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context,DB_NAME,null,DB_VERSION,R.raw.ormlite_config);
        }
```

Here I intialized above class object:

```
  databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```