# Ormlite with proguard enabled doesn't find id field

Tags: java, android, ormlite, android-proguard

I have problem with enabled proguard for my project: 
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot delete class adc because it doesn't have an id field defined

adc class mentioned in exepction is followed:

```
@DatabaseTable(tableName = "zaplanowane_zlecenie")
public class ZaplanowaneZlecenie {
    @DatabaseField(generatedId = true)
    private UUID mZaplanowaneZlecenieId;
    @DatabaseField(columnName = "data")
    private DateTime mZaplanowanaData;
    @DatabaseField(dataType = DataType.SERIALIZABLE)
    private ZlecenieFiltrowane mZaplanowanyAdres;
    @DatabaseField
    @Nullable
    private Double mLatitude;
    @DatabaseField
    @Nullable
    private Double mLongitude;
```

The moment where problem is:

```
mPlannedRepo.deleteForDate(mSelectedData);
```

Code is simple - delete collection found by mDao.queryForEq
While I am not using proguard those methods work well. But if I enable proguard I have mentioned exception and my code doesn't work.

My proguard file(fragment with OrmLite):

```
# ORMLite uses reflection
-keepattributes *DatabaseField*
-keepattributes *DatabaseTable*
-keepattributes *SerializedName*
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod

# Keep the helper class and its constructor
-keep class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper
-keepclassmembers class * extends com.j256.ormlite.android.apptools.OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
}
```

Please help! I have no idea what is going on here.

Comment: I would add last few lines from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853096/proguard-with-ormlite-on-android#answer-31582883 ...btw. mixing polish and english in variable's names is not a good practice

Comment: Thanks, it helped :D

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using these incorrect ProGuard rules (for a list of valid attribute names refer to the [ProGuard manual](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/attributes.html)):

```
-keepattributes *DatabaseField*
-keepattributes *DatabaseTable*
-keepattributes *SerializedName*
```

you need to keep all fields / classes that are annotated using the ORMLite annotations like that:

```
-keep @com.j256.ormlite.table.DatabaseTable class * {
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.DatabaseField <fields>;
    @com.j256.ormlite.field.ForeignCollectionField <fields>;
    <init>();
}
```