# Attempt to invoke interface method after enabling proguard

Tags: java, android, quickblox

I get this error after sign apk file:

> QMAbstractBaseCache: createOrUpdateAll(Collection) - Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object com.j256.ormlite.dao.Dao.callBatchTasks(java.util.concurrent.Callable)' on a null object reference

[image: device-2017-09-23-204319]

I would like to know what all I can try to figure out what is going wrong when I enable proguard .

```
  @Override
public void createOrUpdateAll(final Collection objectsCollection) {
    try {
        if (objectsCollection != null) {
            Log.i(TAG, "createOrUpdateAll_3 :" + objectsCollection.size());
            for (Object object : objectsCollection) {
                Log.i(TAG, "result object getSimpleName :" + (object).getClass().getSimpleName());
            }
        }
        dao.callBatchTasks(new Callable() {
            @Override
            public T call() throws Exception {
                for (Object object : objectsCollection) {
                    createOrUpdate(object);
                }
                notifyObservers(OBSERVE_KEY);
               return null;
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {

        ErrorUtils.logError(TAG, "createOrUpdateAll(Collection) 1 - " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

And in my `proguard-rules.pro` :

```
# OrmLite uses reflection
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.** { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.** { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
-keep class com.j256.**
-keepclassmembers class com.j256.* { *; }
-keep enum com.j256.
-keepclassmembers enum com.j256.* { *; }
-keep interface com.j256.
-keepclassmembers interface com.j256.** { *; }
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9853096/1531971 Also: https://github.com/j256/ormlite-android/issues/44 (It looks like you basically keep everything.)

Comment: Though, given what I see here, it probably has more to do with what sort of object "dao" is. This feels like the implementation of the interface is null.